# How do I unsubscribe from only emails about the Apple TV app?

Tags: email, tv.app

I'm trying to unsubscribe only from emails about TV like this one:

[image: email]

The unsubscribe link takes me to this page, which only has an option for disabling all iTunes emails and not just TV:

[image]